# Extract the list of a JAR classes in C#

Tags: c#, jar

Everything in on the title, is there a way to extract the list of jar classes (equivalent of jar tf) within C# ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AfaIk, jars are just ZIP-Files with a different extension. So any good ZIP libary should do the trick.

A quick google gave me [sharpziplib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) and [this code example](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/SharpZipLib-Zip-Samples.ashx#Unpack_a_Zip_with_full_control_over_the_operation_3) on how to iterate through all files in a ZIP archive.

Comment: Thank you, I heard about it but I just wanted to know if there's another way to do that.